# The DoubleAnimation doesn't work

Tags: wpf, animation

```
//Create my grid and child controls

var layoutRoot = new System.Windows.Controls.Grid 
{
    Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue),
    Name = "layaoutRoot1",
    Height = 400.0,
    VerticalAlignment  = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Stretch,
    HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Stretch
}; 

layoutRoot.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition()
{
    Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto)
});

layoutRoot.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition()
{
    Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star)
});

var myImage = new Image
{
    Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\Path\to\Image\img.png")),
    Stretch = Stretch.UniformToFill,
    Margin = new Thickness(3),
    Width = 50.0,
    Height = 50.0,
};

var textBlocklbl = new TextBlock 
{ 
    Text = "Label Here",
    FontFamily = new FontFamily("Arial"),
    FontSize  = 14.0,
    FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold,
    Margin = new Thickness(3)
};

layoutRoot.Children.Add(myImage);
layoutRoot.Children.Add(textBlocklbl);

System.Windows.Controls.Grid.SetColumn(myImage, 0);
System.Windows.Controls.Grid.SetColumn(textBlocklbl, 1);

grid1.Children.Add(layoutRoot); //grid1 is placed on the MainWindow

Storyboard myStorboard = new Storyboard();
DoubleAnimation myDoubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();

myDoubleAnimation.From = 0.0;
myDoubleAnimation.To = 300.0;
myDoubleAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
myDoubleAnimation.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
//myDoubleAnimation.AutoReverse = true;
myStorboard.Children.Add(myDoubleAnimation);
Storyboard.SetTargetName(myDoubleAnimation, layoutRoot.Name);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(myDoubleAnimation, new PropertyPath(System.Windows.Controls.Grid.HeightProperty));

myStorboard.Begin();
```

Comment: Not sure what your question actually is...

Comment: if you want help, you're gonna need to ask a question. describe what you want and what is going wrong.

Comment: @Tim The animation dont works!

Comment: Ok, stop negative voting

Comment: How does it not work? Does it not do anything? Does it run halfway and stop? Does it animate the wrong thing? You didn't give us enough information to help you. That's why you're getting negative votes.

Comment: I didn't down vote it. I'm just telling you why people would have. You gave us code with no information. You have to help us help you. Now that you've told us that it just doesn't do anything, we know where to start looking. Looks like Snowbear below found the problem though.

Answer (score 5):

Your animation cannot find source for animation. Setting `TargetName` will not work until you put animation into logical tree. Use `StoryBoard.SetTarget(layoutRoot)` instead of `StoryBoard.SetTargetName(layoutRoot.Name)`.

Here is what you could do to resolve it:

1) First of all you could debug it. You just launch the code in Visual Studio in debug mode and keep looking into `Output` window until you see error there. I believe you will see it there soon - then you can fix it. There is still a chance that you won't see any errors.

2) Second, you should try to debug it again. Take your code, paste it into clean solution. Still doesn't work? Great! Keep removing parts of the code which doesn't look related to the issue. `VerticalAlighnment`, `HorizontalAlignment`, do you really need them? Can the issue be reproducible without those properties? Remove them. Less code - easier to debug. Ok, finally you have 10 lines of code but it still doesn't work. Take a sample from MSDN which is working and looks as close to your as possible and find the difference. You can even replace parts of your code with MSDN one to see whether it will help or not.

3) And ok, it still doesn't work, you haven't found any samples and there is no way for you to debug it - you need community help. **Ask question correctly**. If you are a professional developer then probably you've seen it many times - users coming with only one statement `it doesn't work`. You have to test/debug/fix it completely on your own. But those are your clients, they will pay you money eventually. This is free community which is driven only on behalf of our interest. If we are not interested to answer your question - we will never answer it. So ask a question which worth answering. Pasting the code which doesn't work is not enough. You should also provide an information regarding the part which doesn't work. And what have you tried to fix it yourself. If we will think that you're trying to exploit us - we won't answer your question.

Thanks for your time.

**UPDATE** Ok, just tried to debug it. Exactly as I said. Your code gives an exception that `layoutRoot` cannot be found. The exact message is: `No applicable name scope exists to resolve the name 'layaoutRoot1'.`. You just had to run your own code in VS, exactly as you said.